# How can I use SyncSort to convert data to unsigned packed format?

Tags: unsigned, bcd, syncsort

I have a requirement to convert numeric data (stored as character on input) to either packed signed or packed unsigned formats.  I can convert to packed/signed using the "PD" format, but I'm having a difficult time getting unsigned packed data.

For instance, I need a ZD number like 14723 converted to:

042

173

Using PD, I get this (which is fine):

0173

042C

Any suggestions?  We do not have COBOL at this shop and are relying on SyncSort to handle these data conversions.  I'm not seeing a "PK" option in SyncSort, but I've missed things before!

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want a packed-decimal, which always has a sign (even when F for unsigned) in the low-order half-byte. You want Binary Coded Decimal (BCD).

```
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 

  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,OVERLAY=(1,5,ZD,MUL,+10,TO=PD,LENGTH=4)),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,BUILD=(1,3)) 
//SORTIN   DD * 
14723
```

Will give you, in vertical hex:

```
042
173
```

To use an existing BCD, look at field-type `PD0`.